# why does Toast use INotificationManager(notification service) to inform WindowManager to remove itself

Tags: android, android-source

I recently read the Toast sourcecode and find that Toast use notification service(Using Binder) to remove itself after a duration. The process is like the [show method sourcecode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/Toast.java#Toast.show%28%29).

Toast add itself into notification service queues with a duration value and [TN](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/Toast.java#Toast.TN). The notification service will poll the toast from the toast queues, and inform toast to show and dimiss after duration through  [TN](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/Toast.java#Toast.TN).

My question is why Toast use such troublesome style(Two cross process call:Toast call INotificationManager.enqueToast, notification Service call  ITransientNotification.show) to remove itself timing. I think Toast can remove itself by Creating some time tool, such as Hanlder, TimeTask, view.post and so on.

Is it just use toast queues to manager toast and avoid too much toast at the some time.

Explain EDIT：
Toast use WindowManager, It has WindowState and Surface in WindowManagerService. If there are too much Toast at same time, it will lead to high memory usage. My phone is crashed when I add Window by using WindowManager.addView with TYPE_TOAST.

Answer (score 1):

Queue management is a main reason I guess. Otherwise it would have been possible to see multiple Toast from different apps at the same time.